# Django app returning 404 error even if urls seem to be correct according to tutorials

Tags: python, django

I am starting my first django application. I constantly keep getting 404 error after turning on server locally in my computer. I don't see any reason for such return because urls seem to be correct when compared to tutorials and guides on the internet.

This is my urls file inside app (app name is reservations)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

This is urls file in project folder (project name is website)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('reservations/', include('reservations.urls'))
]
```

and this is index function which is supposed to show basic html

```
def index(request):
    response = """<html><body><p>This is home page</p></body></html>"""
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

I thought that my urls are written incorrectly so i tried writing them in different way but it never worked. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to access to similar to that pattern?   `http://localhost:8000/reservations/`

Comment: Yes when i try that it is working

Comment: Ok great, Good luck, Might be you were missing a forward slash at the end of URL, or something like that.